# How can I create a vertical column that spans the whole page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For design purpose, I need a column (vertical) that spans the whole page; pretty much like a never ending pillar that stretches even when I am scrolling. This is what I have gathered.

#HTML

```
 <div class = "container left-bar col-sm-1">
    <div class ="row" id="left-bar-row">
        testing
    </div>
 </div>
```

#css code

```
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left; 
    display: inline;
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: use `min-height: 100vh;`, the column will always have a minimum height of the users screen size

Comment: Try `position: fixed` this will make the pillar to stay on page no matter how other elements load or scroll.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the prompt reply. Really appreciate it. Tried it but no luck. @Liju, Actually I want this pillar of mine to be a continuous (always be at the left side) even when I scroll it. The problem now is that it seems like the container has a height limitation. I can't make it any longer. It just cuts off.

Comment: @Rookie_Hacker so remove that height limitiation, remove `max-height: 100%` and keep `min-height: 100%`

Comment: are you using bootstrap here ?

Comment: if you use bootstrap 4,  set 2 col side by side to start from, then a min-height to fill the entire screen height if content is too small to.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful suggestions.Tried all of your suggestion but it still isn't working. I am still figuring it out.. Will update if I have anything! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left-bar {
  position: fixed; /* keep the element in place even if you are scrolling*/
  height: 100vh; /* to have the page height*/
  width: 100px; /* you can set a width for leftbar*/
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "container left-bar col-sm-1">
    <div class ="row" id="left-bar-row">
        testing
    </div>
 </div>
```